# Free SMS notification of new filtered mail message

Tags: gmail, sms, filter

Does anyone know how to get notified by SMS for free when a new mail message has been received in the inbox. I am using a script which notifies to my Gmail account if one of my websites are slow or down. During night or off time I could not check my mails and I'm wondering if I could get notified by SMS(ONLY FILTERED MAILS) for FREE when I receive a mail. I know the site www.way2sms.com and felt it difficult to configure. If anybody using any method or site for this, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: using the gmail filter approach is great, but it sends the ENTIRE email message- when the sms message length is exceeded, my carrier, Sprint, rejects it and it doesn't work.. Any way to just send the subject line and first part of the body ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not configure your GMail account to forward a copy of the specific messages (based on the sender) to the email address of your phone.

Comment: Or alternatively have your monitoring system email your phone directly, either in lieu of or in addition to the message to your gmail account.

Comment: NO idea how to do this!

Comment: I know setting forwarder but to phone, don't know how.

Comment: Every cell phone has an email address. It's normally in the format: cellphonenumber@carrierdomain.com. For instance, if Verizon is your carrier and your phone number is 555-555-5555 then your phone's email address is: 5555555555@vtext.com. You just need to find out what the email domain for your phone is and set up a forward in Gmail.

Comment: I'm finding difficult to find out my phones carrier domain. Mine is TATA gsm phone-India.

Comment: You should call their technical or customer support and ask them.

Comment: Of course I didn't get my carrier domain!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [googlecl](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) for Nagios notifications. I add an "event" to my calendar with *at HH:MM am/pm* with HH and MM set to +2 minutes from current time and get an SMS with short event description in 1 minute before the "event" begins.

May be it is possible to configure you e-mail checing daemon to execute a script if a filtered mail is in the indox.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it costs money to send smses. Unless your mobile phone provider has the Email to SMS feature builtin (Ex: yourmobilenumber@bell.ca) then you'll have to pay for that service with a third party.

I'm currently building a service called [gmail2sms](http://www.gmail2sms.com) but it will cost you a few cents for each SMS (since an SMS relay charges for it). This should be ready in about 2 weeks, let me know if you would be interested in using it.

Comment: gmail2sms is redirecting to under construction page. I'll have to try after some days

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of obtaining SMS alert from gmail.com using Google Calendar
http://gmail2sms.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-get-sms-notification-of-new-mail.html